# Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I am using the following code to make a knex connection, but frequently the error occurred

> Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?

Can anyone please suggest the solution for this issue?

```
var knexConn = reqKnex({
        client: pClient,
        native: false,
        connection: pConn,
        searchPath: pSearchPath,
        pool: {
            max: 7,
            min: 3,
            acquireTimeout: 60 * 1000
        }
    });


function getTransactionScope(pKnex, callback) {
    try {
        pKnex.transaction(function(trx) {
            return callback(trx);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

function ExecuteSQLQuery(pTranDB, pTrx, pQuery, pCallback) {
    try {
        var query = pTranDB.raw(pQuery);

        if (pTrx) {
            query = query.transacting(pTrx);
        }
        query.then(function(res, error) {
            try {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    return pCallback(res, error);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            return pCallback(null, error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

function Commit(pTrx, pIsCommit) {
    try {
        if (pIsCommit) {
            pTrx.commit();
        } else {
            pTrx.rollback();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: (_Do_ you have `.transacting(trx)` (or close) calls(dynamically)?)

Comment: Yes, I am using the trx for applying the transactionscope. I have updated the full code in above post. pls revisit the code and suggest me

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: anyone able to resolve this error ?

Comment: Does anyone find the solution for this bug ?

Comment: Don't use `propagationError: false`
https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3455

Comment: In my case, I specified the wrong port.

Answer (score 59):

I solved this problem with these versions:

```
"knex": "^0.21.1",
"objection": "^2.1.3",
"pg": "^8.0.3"
```

Comment: It's a helpful one though: Updating to these versions solved my issue. Apparently node 14 just came out and broke something in knex or the pg driver or somewhere... Connections fail and all you get is `Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?`.

Comment: Was encountering this issue with node 14 + pg 8.0.2. Updating pg to 8.0.3 solved my issue!

Comment: thx @ddriver1 saved me a lot of time. I update only the pg and the problem was solved.

Comment: Any idea why these versions fixed the issue @bratislav?

Comment: what is the "objection" library for? I don't see it as a dependency in my code?

Comment: @swateek `objectionjs` is an orm-like for JS/TS. It uses Knex under the hood.

Answer (score 21):

I had this issue recently, and I had just updated to Node v14.2.0

[image]

This version seems to have a breaking change to knex. Luckily I have NVM so I switch to another version (v12.16.3) and this solved the issue.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Confirmed this. I was on node 14.4.0 and moved back to 12.14.1 (picked the version a teammate was using) with nvm and all is well.

Comment: I had this issue today after updating from Node 16 to Node 17 when running e2e tests using mocha. Downgraded back to latest 16 and everything came back to normal.

Answer (score 9):

I also experienced this problem when I upgraded to node `14.0.0`. I reverted my node version and this problem went away.

Comment: I confirm that too! I experienced that before! And after tracking that the only change was updgrading node i changed the version with nvm! And it worked! This time i forget again hhhh! And that reminded me!

Answer (score 9):

I've made some test. Here is the result.

```
"knex": "^0.20.8",
"objection": "^2.1.2",
"pg": "^7.14.0"
```

Using these versions my app works well on node `12.22.7` but I've got the timeout issue on `14.18.1`.

Updating `pg` to version `8.0.2`:

- `12.22.7` -> it works correctly
- `14.18.1` -> knex timeout error

Updating `pg` to version `8.0.3`:

- `12.22.7` -> it works correctly
- `14.18.1` -> it works correctly

The issue goes away on node `14` when `pg` version is `8.0.3`.

Comment: In some cases, just increasing the timeout helps. Try setting acquireConnectionTimeout  in knex(say 50*1000)

Comment: This should be accepted answer. It works with node v16.13.1 also.

Comment: Ditto.  This should be the accepted answer.    "pg": "^8.7.1",     "objection": "^3.0.1",     "knex": "^0.95.15", works with the stable release of node 17.3.0.  Thank you

Answer (score 7):

The attribute **propagateCreateError** should be set to **false** to prevent the Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call? error.

Example pool configuration:

```
"pool": {
  "min": 2,
  "max": 6,
  "createTimeoutMillis": 3000,
  "acquireTimeoutMillis": 30000,
  "idleTimeoutMillis": 30000,
  "reapIntervalMillis": 1000,
  "createRetryIntervalMillis": 100,
  "propagateCreateError": false // <- default is true, set to false
},
```

**Explanation**:
The **propagateCreateError** is *set to true by default in Knex* and throws a **TimeoutError** if the first create connection to the database fails, preventing tarn (the connection pool manager) from re-connecting automatically.

The solution is to set **propagateCreateError** to false thus enabling **knex** to automatically reconnect on create connection failure instead of throwing the error.

**AuroraDB**:
In case you are connecting to an AuroraDB instance, currently it has a very long startup time, causing the TimeoutError on every new cold-start, to fix this, set AWS Console -> RDS -> AuroraDB Instance -> Pause compute capacity after consecutive minutes of inactivity: 1440 hours to prevent the database from going to sleep completely.

*For Detail explanation please see*
https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2820

Comment: Thank @AliRaza, my head was spinning before reading that....

Comment: Word of warning - the Knex team doesn't support this option, knex needs this to be `true`

https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3455

Comment: The **propagateCreateError = false** solution is not recommended by knex core-contributor "elhigu", always consider what these have to guys say. He says, and I quote, "That should never be set to false with knex".  For more information, read [https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/2108]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when deploying a strapi app to heroku.
In my package.json I had the following versions:

- `"knex": "<0.20.0"`
- `"pg": "^7.18.2"`

I also had the following node engine configuration:

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=10.0.0",
  "npm": ">=6.0.0"
},
```

Changing the versions to `<0.21.1` and `^8.0.3` (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61482183/4696783 ) and changing node engine to `12.16.x` (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61942001/4696783) solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else coming across this, it may also result from a typo in your database host name (as was the case for me).

Comment: or a proxy between server and database. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I had to patch `knex` npm package to retry acquiring pool connection atleast once before throwing error incase of knex timeout issue. Open file `node_modules/knex/lib/client.js`. You will see this method:

```
  async acquireConnection() {
    if (!this.pool) {
      throw new Error('Unable to acquire a connection');
    }
    try {
      const connection = await this.pool.acquire().promise;
      debug('acquired connection from pool: %s', connection.__knexUid);
      return connection;
    } catch (error) {
      let convertedError = error;
      if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
        convertedError = new KnexTimeoutError(
          'Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. ' +
            'Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?'
        );
      }
      throw convertedError;
    }
  },
```

Replace with:

```
async acquireConnection() {
    if (!this.pool) {
      throw new Error('Unable to acquire a connection');
    }
    try {
      const connection = await this.pool.acquire().promise;
      debug('acquired connection from pool: %s', connection.__knexUid);
      return connection;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.warn('Acquire connection error, retrying once');
      try {
        if (!this.pool) {
          this.logger.warn('Pool has been destroyed, initializing again');
          this.initializePool();
        }
        const connection = await this.pool.acquire().promise;
        debug('acquired connection from pool: %s', connection.__knexUid);
        return connection;
      } catch (error) {
        let convertedError = error;
        if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
          convertedError = new KnexTimeoutError(
            'Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. ' +
              'Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?'
          );
        }
        throw convertedError;
      }
    }
  },
```

then patch the package

```
yarn add -D patch-package
yarn patch-package knex
```

then create a `postinstall` npm script so that it runs automatically after each install:

```
"postinstall": "patch-package -p1 -i patches/<name of your patch file>"
```

PS: using node `v14.17.6`

Answer (score 1):

Using NodeJS 14.7 LTS in a nginx server that runs pm2 to manage projects, all I needed to do was run `pm2 reload {projectID}` to "fix" it, if anyone faces it with the same conditions as me, try it first before changing packages, and downgrading your NodeJS.

Comment: Same problem for me and the reloading of the application fixed the problemi. It is a temporary fix but could be done every hour with the --cron_restart option as a restart. The way to do a reload instead is to use the crontab, in any.

Answer (score 1):

Also check that your IP is among trusted sources on your DB. That was the issue for me:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have not changed anything and you've got this error, this maybe been caused of an external db connection. My  case: customer didn't payed for the service.

Answer (score 0):

Some points can generate this error, among them are these:

- Case you work behind a proxy this error can happen because you proxy in command line not configured fine. verify the envs `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` case your SO is linux.
- Case your connection is with ORACLE Database can be necessary configrure environments viriables to instantClient.

  Exemple:

  ```
     export PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_1:$PATH
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_1
  ```
- Case your conection is with oracle database and your application work with rabbitMQ (PREFETCH) or any service than use many work threads, this link https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-162-connections-threads-and-parallelism can help you.
  By default node use thread pool size 4, increasing the number of worker threads may improve throughput and prevent deadlocks

> **16.2 Connections, Threads, and Parallelism**
>
> If you open more than four connections, such as via increasing poolMax, you should increase the
> number of worker threads available to node-oracledb. A thread pool
> that is too small can cause connection requests to fail with the error
> NJS-040: connection request timeout or NJS-076: connection request
> rejected.
>
> The thread pool size should be equal to, or greater than, the maximum
> number of connections. If the application does database and
> non-database work concurrently, then additional threads could also be
> required for optimal throughput.
>
> Increase the thread pool size by setting the environment variable
> **[UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE](https://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html)** before starting Node.js.
>
> For example, on Linux your `package.json` may have a script like:
>
> ```
> "scripts": {
>     "start": "export UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=10 && node index.js"   }, 
> . . .
> ```
>
> Or, on Windows:
>
> ```
> "scripts": {
>     "start": "SET UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=10 && node index.js"   }, 
> . . .
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when migrating from node `v12.16.1` to `v14.18.1` (latest 14 for now).
Steps to fix the issue:

- bump knex version `=0.20.1` --> `0.95.11`
- bump pg version `7.12.1` --> `8.7.1`
- remove `knex-migrate` module and do migrations via raw knex

```
       const [totalMigrations, executedMigrations] = await knex.migrate.up({
           directory: require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'migrations'),
           disableMigrationsListValidation: true, 
       });
       logger.info('Migration success', { totalMigrations, executedMigrations });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"express": "^4.16.2",
"knex": "^0.14.2",
"objection": "^2.1.3",
"pg": "^8.0.3",
```

i fixed my problem (end of the 4 day)

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this here for others who might come in, my client is `mssql`
I moved to

1. latest `lts/gallium` (v16.5.1)
2. latest knex `2.1.0`
3. latest tedious `14.5.0`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for a long time, but then I realized that the `config.connection` configuration was connecting to a "secrets" service to get the database password (i.e. this was a secrets manager provided by GCP) and this service would sometimes take longer than expected (the Knex config.connection block can be async).

Long story short, the "secrets" service would flake and timeout unexpectedly (I don't think it was scaled to handle secrets like this), but then Knex would  either cast the thrown timeout error as its own or Knex's timeout would fire first. The end result was a cryptic timeout error thrown by Knex.

This was really hard to pin down since it was random. So long as the secrets server was fast to respond the error was nowhere to be found. Thank god I decided to refactor the secrets to be loaded as ENV variables. Once I did that then I realized what was going on.

So the lesson here is to always load secrets data as ENV variables!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved when add correct port at connection setting
You can find connection port at PostgreSql with right click
[Connection configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y8NC.png)

Answer (score -1):

In my application I was facing (sometime in between)

```
TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
```

My config of knex is

```js
const config = client: process.env.CLIENT,
  connection: {
    host: process.env.DBHOST,
    user: process.env.DBUSER,
    password: process.env.DBPASS,
    database: process.env.DATABASE
  },
  pool: { min: 0, max: 30, acquireTimeoutMillis: 60 * 1000 },
  seeds: {
    directory: './db/sds'
  },
  migrations: {
    directory: './db/mg'
  }
}

import knexLib from 'knex';
export const con = knexLib(config);
```

and I'm using it something like

```js
import {con} from './con';
import {FormatError} from '../err'

const handler = (req)=>{
  const trx = con.transaction();
  try{
    const result = await con('insert-table').transacting(trx).insert(req.list).returning('*');
    const resultOfLog = await Promise.all(
      result.map((o) => {
        return con('log-table')
          .insert({event_id: 1, resource: o.id});
        })
    );
    return result;
  } catch(error){
    return new FormatError(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue,
taking into consideration: 
[this post](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2820#issuecomment-481710112).

> The attribute propagateCreateError should be set to false to prevent the Timeout 
>    acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call? error.
>
> Example pool configuration:
>
> "pool": {
>     "min": 2,
>     "max": 6,
>     "createTimeoutMillis": 3000,
>     "acquireTimeoutMillis": 30000,
>     "idleTimeoutMillis": 30000,
>     "reapIntervalMillis": 1000,
>     "createRetryIntervalMillis": 100,
>     "propagateCreateError": false // <- default is true, set to false
>   },
>   Explanation:
>
> The propagateCreateError is set to true by default in Knex and throws a TimeoutError if the first create connection to the database fails, preventing tarn (the connection pool manager) from re-connecting automatically.
>
> The solution is to set propagateCreateError to false thus enabling knex to automatically reconnect on create connection failure instead of throwing the error.

and [this post](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/2790#issuecomment-475123374):

I have made the following configuration

```
module.exports = {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host: config.testDB.host,
        user: config.testDB.userName,
        port: config.testDB.port,
        password: config.testDB.password,
        database: 'testdb',
        charset: 'utf8'
    },
    pool: {
        max: 50,
        min: 2,
        // acquireTimeout: 60 * 1000,
        // createTimeoutMillis: 30000,
        // acquireTimeoutMillis: 30000,
        // idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
        // reapIntervalMillis: 1000,
        // createRetryIntervalMillis: 100,
        propagateCreateError: false // <- default is true, set to false
    },
    migrations: {
        tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work for you, try setting propagateError to true and uncomment

```
 "idleTimeoutMillis": 30000,
 "createTimeoutMillis": 30000,
 "acquireTimeoutMillis": 30000
```