# Why ami I getting TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js, objection.js

We are getting Knex timeout error mostly during high traffic in production with postgresql database. The knex config is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  client: 'pg',
  connection: 
    process.env.DATABASE_URL || {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME
    },
  migrations: {
    directory: './migrations'
  },
  seeds: {
    directory: './seeds'
  },
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 20
  }
};
```

We tried removing transactions from 2 heavy controllers and somehow optimized queries up to a point. But we are still getting this issue. We are using node 14. and following are the version of related dependencies

```
"knex": "^2.1.0",
"objection": "^3.0.0",
"pg": "^8.6.0"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435315/knex-timeout-acquiring-a-connection-the-pool-is-probably-full-are-you-missing)

Comment: Seems to me `max: 20` is not high enough. I would look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database, but I'm guessing is you are out running your connection limit.

Comment: @MichelFloyd we looked over everything based on it, but nothing helped us. We have been running on same environment for almost an year but this issue started showing up just few months back. We even tried to remove transaction from few places but the issue didn't fix but the occurrence of the error was reduced by significant amount.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am afraid if increasing max pool size would hamper the performance of database?

Comment: Worse then?: *Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call*

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you we set pool to 30 and it did fix the knex timeout as we didn't receive any error. But the root cause of the issue was from frontend where we allowed users to spam button clicks and during high traffic, database was not able to handle the load with 20 pools.