# Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call? [2024]

Tags: database, postgresql, nestjs, knex.js, supabase

I'm encountering a KnexTimeoutError when attempting to deploy my Node.js application's database changes using a series of npm scripts that utilize Knex migrations. My goal is to rollback all migrations, apply the latest migrations, and then seed the database, executed in a single npm command. The specific command I'm running is,

```
"deploy:fresh": "npm run knex:migrate:rollback:all && npm run knex:migrate:latest && npm run knex:seed:run"
```

I have been running this command quite a lot of times during development.

My stack,

- NestJS
- Objection.js ORM (with knex.js)
- PostgreSQL (on Supabase)

I know a similar alternative question ([Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435315/knex-timeout-acquiring-a-connection-the-pool-is-probably-full-are-you-missing)) exists, but it's too old and the versions suggested are too old for me now.

- "knex": "^3.1.0"
- "objection": "^3.1.4",
- "pg": "^8.11.3",

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see your knex settings. In the connection object, there are (optional) settings for the connection pool.

```
{
  ..., // the rest of the settings
  pool: { min: 1, max: 20 },
}
```

You could try to up the max to something than the default, which is 10.
But you should know that something in your script is likely a bit unhealthy if it eats up all those connections. This is more of a plaster than a remedy...

Btw, make sure that the connection to the db works in the first place so that is not the issue.